# How to make sure important team members leaving doesn't impact knowledge transfer on a project?

Tags: team, knowledge-transfer

I have recently joined a new company, and after 4 month of my joining, 2 of my team members are leaving this company. Technically, the project is not doing so good, and the team members also didn't get the promotion they were expecting.

My reporting manager is expecting from me that I should make sure that I know each and everything related to their work so that the project won't be impacted by them leaving. How can I fulfill this expectation?

1) What are the documents I should ask the team members to prepare?
2) How to get knowledge they gained in this company during their 2 years of working?
3) What can I do more to make sure that I am capable of handling this project by my own by the time they leave?

Comment: Hey user, the thing to do, if the linked duplicate doesn't answer your question, is to [edit] this post and clarify how the other answers don't help you. Being more clear in your post helps ensure you get the best answers possible.